# On Mac, after downloading a file, how to you do a checksum?

Tags: macos, download, checksum, verification

I want to do a checksum on a file I downloaded on my Mac. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal window type the md5 command followed by the file location.

```
md5 Downloads/myfile
```

Comment: For SHA-1: `openssl sha1 <file>`. Other algorithms also available; see [ *openssl* ](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/openssl.1ssl.html). If you want an old school checksum see [ *cksum* ](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cksum.1.html) (MD5 and SHA-1 are actually cryptographic hash functions, not simple checksums).